# notification being dismissed after app destroyed after updates are triggered

Tags: java, android, service

The android docs state that for a service to be started, the `onStartCommand` has to be implemented. When I made the `service`, and start the service using `ContextCompat.startForegroundService(...)`, then it's `onStartCommand` method gets executed, and at this point *even when I quit the app* , the service doesn't stop (*as expected*).

But, later when I make updates to the notification by changing the text displayed, I use the `notificationManager.notify()` method, and *now when I quit the app*, the service automatically stops. I wonder if we are suppose to force call onStartCommand on every notification update, somehow(like should we update the notification with `ContextCompat.startForegroundService`?   I've tested this from `api level 19` to `api level 27` and the behaviour is all the same. How can I maintain the property of the service as `started` even after I update the notification?

Comment: Hi, how do you update notification when the foreground service is running?

Comment: @Zain, Hello,  as I've mentioned, I use the `notificationManager.notify(...)` methods to update the notification when the app UI is alive(i.e. it's onDestroy or onPause hasn't been called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if we are suppose to force call `onStartCommand` on every notification update,

No you are not forced to call `onStartCommand` on every notification update

> somehow(like should we update the notification with `ContextCompat.startForegroundService`? I've tested this from API level 19 to API level 27 and the behaviour is all the same. How can I maintain the property of the service as started even after I update the notification?

You should call `ContextCompat.startForegroundService` only once for starting a `ForegroundService`.

In order to update the `ForegroundSerice` notification without being destroyed when you quit your app, you can use [`startForeground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) every time you want to update the foreground service notification.

A famous example on this to update a downloading service with the download progress to something like a `ProgressBar`.

**The important thing:** you need to make sure you use the same notification ID while calling `startForeground()`

`startForeground()` won't call `onStartCommand`; If that could be possible, then I guess this would make an endless loop.

Whenever you want to stop the foreground service, and submit a normal notification (Download complete in download example), then you can submit a normal notification with `notificationManager.notify()`, and this will allow the user to dismiss the notification by swiping it.

### **UPDATE: As discussed in chat**

**Issue**: When submitting a normal notification after the foreground service is stopped; the normal notification is dismissed as well.

**Cause**: This is because you use the same notification ID that you've used with the foreground service, so stopping the foreground service will also dismiss the normal notification.

**Solution**: make sure to have different notification IDs of the foreground service notification and the normal notification that is dispatched upon stopping the foreground service.

Also make sure to call below to stop the foreground service:

```
stopForeground(true);
stopSelf();
```

Comment: I actually use the service to play music, but, this seems to work when the music is playing and I destroy the app, but even though I use `startForeground()` for updating the notification while pausing as well, after I pause the music and quit the app, the service is destroyed, do you know why that might be happening?

Comment: I also don't unbind the service or anything during pausing, I infact invoke the same method for playing but, update the notification with a different icon only

Comment: I found the reason was that I was calling the stopForeground(false) while updating the notification, now, it doesn't get destroyed, but __the user can't swipe dismiss the notification __, and I even call the notificationManager.notify() method, do you know the reason why?

Comment: You must call stopForeground somewhere to stop the foreground service before submitting any notificationManager. notify()

Comment: If you share something that could make it more clear

Comment: @juztcode can you share the scenario you want to fulfill in steps, say when the user play the music, start the service, then update the track length, ... when you want to stop the foreground service .. something like that

Comment: okay, its hard to post all the code, so, let me give you snippets of how I do each, just a sec

Comment: as far the notification updates are concerned, this is the only bit of code: https://pastebin.com/97W6JhaD , yet the notification is being destroyed when I quit the app, and when the music is paused. When the music is not paused and the app is quit, then it is working flawlessly. But, I'd also want the service to not be dismissed once the app is closed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224861/discussion-between-zain-and-juztcode).

Comment: @juztcode Something not normal as your chat messages didn't give me notification (maybe the notification is dismiss able :) .. please check the chat discussion section I just updated on it

Comment: hello, thanks for the reply. Yes, I actually had done something like you mentioned in the chat and it had worked. :-) I'll accept the answer for the time being, but do update the answer as you've mentioned in the chat room. :-)

Comment: glad that it helped .. sure will update it .. thank you bro :)